# I want to use LINQ to extract the strings that match the class property strings and the strings in the prepared list

Tags: c#, linq

## Prerequisites

- A class called AAA has a string type property called BBB.
- BBB contains a character string such as "1,5,6,12".
- There is another int type list called CCC (eg [1,2,4,7,9,12,15]).

## want to achieve

I want to use LINQ to get a list of AAAs that match at least one in BBB and CCC from DbSet  in C#.

## Example

```
AAA1 → AAA1.BBB = "1,2,3"
AAA2 → AAA2.BBB = "4,5,6"
AAA3 → AAA3.BBB = "7,8,9"

CCC = [1,3,4]
```

In this case I want a list of AAA1 and AAA2!!!

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any code you have written for this? Can you share that code here and explain what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: It might also help understand the problem if you first solve it without LINQ, just using foreach loops and if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: provided they are always INT and also they are separated by "," this solution will work

```
    public class StringNumber
    {
        public string Numbers { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new StringNumber { Numbers = "1,2,3" };
        var b = new StringNumber { Numbers = "4,5,6" };
        var c = new StringNumber { Numbers = "7,8,9" };

        List<StringNumber> stringNumbers = new List<StringNumber>() { a, b, c };

        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 10 };
        //ToList is needed unless you want it to actually remove from the stringNumbers!
        var result = GetAllListsWithNumber(numbers, stringNumbers.ToList());
    }

    public static List<StringNumber> GetAllListsWithNumber(List<int> numbers, List<StringNumber> stringNumbers)
    {
        stringNumbers.RemoveAll(x => !x.Numbers
                                        .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                        .Select(number => Convert.ToInt32(number))
                                    .Any(number => numbers.Contains(number)));

        return stringNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: Hm, why not you create the numbers variable just as an array ? Also what is for stringNumbers variable passed to the function as a List ? Even double list ? You can just return IEnumerable<StringNumber> there

Comment: Is there any reason why i would want to return an IEnumerable instead of a List? Im not saying i cant, i didnt see the need to return as generic as possible. So i choosed to work with list but bear in mind this is just an example for him. You could have of course worked with arrays. and even know im watching it. It would have been better to use Where Linq statement instead of removing this way, so i could have returned a new copy of the list without modifying the original one. The Main method was just for him how to implement the function, only method relevant would be GetAllListsWithNumber

Comment: Well, yes, and here is the reason - a List<> reserve a lot of memory, there it's no need to add/remove list items, it could be done beautifully by just using Linq

Comment: As i stated i knew it could be done. There is no good or bad reason why i didnt do it. There will always be room for improvement. But also there is no need to optimize before its actually needed

Comment: Then why are you writting bad code when it's more simple to write good one ? It's someting like... Yeah, we call it "Indian code"